# used create-react-app and I am unable to parse simple JSON file

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, loader

I am having trouble parsing my JSON file due to not having a proper loader in my webpack.config file. I am using create-react-app and these files are locked and included via scripts. When I tried to address this issue last night, I added webpack which was a mistake since create-react-app already had created this for me. I am not sure what I am doing wrong -- whether it be the format of my json file or if I have the incorrect dependencies.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import TriviaQuestions from '../questions'
    
    class TriviaGame extends Component {
    
      state = {
        triviaStart: false,
        triviaReset: false,
        totalCorrect: 0,
        questionNumber: 0,
        totalQuestions: 0,
        question: '',
        answerOne: '',
        answerTwo: '',
        answerThree: '',
        answerFour: '',
        correct: '',
      };
    
      newQuestion = () => {
        if (this.state.triviaStart === true) {
          this.setState({
            question: Questions[this.state.questionNumber].question,
            answerOne: Questions[this.state.questionNum].answerOne,
            answerTwo: Questions[this.state.questionNum].answerTwo,
            answerThree: Questions[this.state.questionNum].answerThree,
            answerFour: Questions[this.state.questionNum].answerFour,
            correct: Questions[this.state.questionNum].correct,
            totalQuestions: Questions.length
          })
        }
      };
    
      triviaGameStart = () => {
        this.setState({
          triviaStart: true,
          questionNumber: this.state.questionNumber + 1
        })
        this.newQuestion()
      };
    };
    
    export default TriviaGame
```

my json file -- changing the export syntax does not change whether I can access the file from triviaGame, my json begins parsing the file and fails:

```
    [
      {
        "question": "In Pokemon Blue/Red, whom does Gary choose if you 
        take Bulbasaur?"
        "answerOne": "Pikachu"
        "answerTwo": "Eevee"
        "answerThree": "Charmander"
        "answerFour": "Squirtle"
        "correct": "3"
      },
      {
        "question": "Low kick is super effective against which Pokemon?"
        "answerOne": "Lapras"
        "answerTwo": "Arcanine"
        "answerThree": "Pidgeotto"
        "answerFour": "Clefairy"
        "correct": "4"
      },
      {
        "question": "What is the name of the Professor who gives your 
        first pokemon in Pokemon Red/Blue/Yellow?"
        "answerOne": "Professor Elm"
        "answerTwo": "Professor Birch"
        "answerThree": "Professor Oak"
        "answerFour": "Professor Pine"
        "correct": "3"
      },
      {
        "question": "In Pokemon Yellow, at which level does Pikachu learn 
        slam?"
        "answerOne": "19"
        "answerTwo": "20"
        "answerThree": "21"
        "answerFour": "22"
        "correct": "2"
      },
      {
        "question": "In the original Pokemon series, Gyrados is which two 
        types?"
        "answerOne": "Water/Dragon"
        "answerTwo": "Flying/Dragon"
        "answerThree": "Water/Flying"
        "answerFour": "Dragon/Electric"
        "correct": "3"
      },
      {
        "question": "In the original Pokemon series, Normal type moves 
        are super effective against which type(s)?"
        "answerOne": "Ghost"
        "answerTwo": "Fighting"
        "answerThree": "Both of the above"
        "answerFour": "None of the above"
        "correct": "4"
      },
      {
        "question": "In the original Pokemon, what is the name of the 
        item needed to engage with Ghost type pokemon?"
        "answerOne": "Silph Scope "
        "answerTwo": "Cursed Trinket"
        "answerThree": "Lavender Amulet"
        "answerFour": "Pokeflute"
        "correct": "1"
      },
      {
        "question": "Which pokemon can be caught in both the Safari Zone, 
        as well as Cerulean Cave?"
        "answerOne": "Kangaskhan"
        "answerThree": "Chancey"
        "answerTwo": "Dragonair"
        "answerFour": "Golem"
        "correct": "2"
      },
      {
        "question": "Where is Missingo located?"
        "answerOne": "Viridian City"
        "answerTwo": "Mt. Moon"
        "answerThree": "Cinnibar Island"
        "answerFour": "Rocket Hideout"
        "correct": "3"
      },
      {
        "question": "Which Pokemon do I prefer?"
        "answerOne": "Dragonite"
        "answerTwo": "Machamp"
        "answerThree": "Gengar"
        "answerFour": "Alakazam"
        "correct": "1"
      },
    ]
```

and here is the complete error message I receive:

```
Failed to compile
./src/questions.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected string in JSON at position 94 while parsing '[
  {
    "question": "In Pokemon Blue/R'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 94 while parsing '[
  {
    "question": "In Pokemon Blue/R'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Thank you so much for any help.  I'm happy to provide more info if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Make ',' in the end of each line and the '/' return ' \  / ' :

```
 {
    "question": "In Pokemon Blue\/ Red, whom does Gary choose if you 
    take Bulbasaur?",
    "answerOne": "Pikachu",
    "answerTwo": "Eevee",
    "answerThree": "Charmander",
    "answerFour": "Squirtle",
    "correct": "3",
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, the dependencies were all there but my formatting was a wildly sloppy. thank you